# Add PHP code before any other code in Wordpress template, on a per post basis

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I'm trying to figure out how to add some PHP code into my template, before anything else (line:1).

I want to do this using a custom field in the post itself. I'm experimenting with wordpress hooks, but can only seem to be able to insert HTML/JS, and only within the actual header.php, and not before it.

Is there a specific Hook I should use for this, and also, is it possible to add PHP to the template in this manner?

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding what you want to do? You're probably going to want to hook into the ['init' action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access custom fields of the post, you probably need to hook into the `wp` hook which fires after the post object is created and conditional functions are available, but before `get_header` is fired. Something like this in your functions.php file:

```
<?php
function my_function(){
  global $post;
  if( is_single() ){
    $my_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my key', true ); // Assumes your custom meta returns a single value
    if( 'value expected' == $my_meta ){
      // My PHP code to run goes here
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'my_function' );
```

Comment: You should probably ask a question to verify whether he needs WP to be created. An important thing to note is that the `'wp'` hook fires AFTER headers and query variables are set. You answer may be correct, depending on his use case.

Comment: Good point. I've assumed (perhaps wrongly? let's see if Chris chimes in) that he needs it because he wants to access a custom meta for an individual post. I guess the big question is whether he needs it before headers are sent.

Comment: actually, yes, at first i thought this looked perfect, but i do need it before any headers are sent. Its basically some redirect functionality that I'm building, and needs to fire before any headers.